# Find and Replace based on set criteria/table - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an expense file with a Description column that I want to categorize into a new "Category" column.  For example, anything in the Description column that contains "Meijer" would categorize as "Groceries", anything in the Description column that contains "Comed" would categorize as "Utilities", etc.

Is there a way to connect my "Key" table into the Category column without a lengthy formula?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S7Cx.png)

I tried the equation:  *IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("meijer",A1)),"Utilities",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("comed",A1)),"Bills & Utilities"))* however that got lengthy and very manual.

I've also tried searching for a "find and replace if a condition is met" equation, but have had no luck.  (And if possible, I'd like to avoid using power query)

Comment: How many different merchants do you have? What if you do a vlookup on the first 4 letters against a key table? Could be a very simple formula, but might get a little more complicated if some merchants have only 3 letters.

Comment: 50+ merchants.  I like that idea, but the only problem is sometimes a "Meijer" entry may not being with those 4 letters.  I'd rather not get too hung up on a "contains" formula, but I think that might be the best route

Comment: With only 50 merchants, it should be very quick to accomplish. Maybe Meijer needs two key rows (MEIJ and MIEJ) or whatever pattern you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your text is entered starting with cell A1, then in cell B2 and below you put this formula:

```
=INDEX(FILTER($E$3:$E$6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$3:$D$6,$A2))),1)
```

It would look better and be easier to maintain if you convert both ranges to tables.

To help others respond faster, it would help if you put the data in an Excel file somewhere in the cloud. That would have saved me time in typing your data.